# Running Lucee (tomcat) in docker with supervisord as CMD, weird path issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, tomcat7, dockerfile

I have create a Dockerfile to run my Lucee (Coldfusion on Tomcat) service with Apache.
This all works fine, however, I have one subsite where I run an index.cfm in the apache webroot.
Strangely, I get an error message that the file can not be found:

```
Page /supervisord-c/index.cfm [/var/www/project/tracker/root/supervisord-c/index.cfm] not found
```

The file is actually sitting at `/var/www/project/tracker/root/index.cfm]`.

Now is supervisord the last command in my dockerfile

```
...config stuff..
# Run config scripts
ADD scripts/setup.sh /root/setup.sh
RUN chmod +x /root/setup.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/root/setup.sh"]

# Copy supervisord.conf
COPY scripts/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/

# Expose HTTP and HTTPS ports
EXPOSE 80 443

# Engage
CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

What supervisord does is run Apache and Tomcat Catelina.

I got rid of supervisord and ran CMD `["/usr/sbin/apachectl","-DFOREGROUND"]` and manually started Catelina. 
Websites where working, but the subsite with the `index.cfm` now displayed the following error:

```
Page /usr/sbin/index.cfm [/var/www/project/tracker/root/usr/sbin/index.cfm] not found
```

So there is definitely a connection at the last CMD I execute and how it affects my tomcat webroot.

Any idea how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the issue was. The Lucee dockerfile adds a proxy pass to your apache.conf.
This looks like:

```
proxypass="\n\n<IfModule mod_proxy.c> \n
    ProxyPreserveHost On \n
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cf[cm])(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2 \n
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cfchart)(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2 \n
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cfml)(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2 \n
    # optional mappings \n
    #ProxyPassMatch ^/flex2gateway/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/flex2gateway/$1 \n
    #ProxyPassMatch ^/messagebroker/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/messagebroker/$1 \n
    #ProxyPassMatch ^/flashservices/gateway(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/flashservices/gateway$1 \n
    #ProxyPassMatch ^/openamf/gateway/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/openamf/gateway/$1 \n
    #ProxyPassMatch ^/rest/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/rest/$1 \n
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8888/ \n
</IfModule> \n"

echo -e $proxypass >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

What I never noticed, that when I look in my docker containers `apache2.conf` file that I would see

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cf[cm])(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/supervisord-c
```

So the $1 added my the `supervisord-c` mapping to my proxy pass. Not sure why but removing it solved the issue.